# How to detect when an audio file has finished playing?

Tags: android, android-studio, audio

I'm playing an audio file and recording at the same time using an object of MediaPlayer and AudioRecorder. I want to stop the recording thread as soon as the tune being played is finished. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //here you can stop your recording thread.

        }
```

Comment: If I already initialized an object of MediaPlayer (mPlayer), would the code then become  ...public void onCompletion(mPlayer) {....

Comment: the mediaplayer object (mp) returned in this method is not your player... but the one returned by callback method

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that, thank you! Would I still need to stop and release the player if I use this method?

Comment: Yes...this method is a listener to the completion of player.it will be triggered after the player completes its work.it will not itself stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the end of the playback using instance of [`MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) and registering a [callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) to your `MediaPlayer` instance